# SSRS page break based on value of a text box

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I currently have a report which has a **tablix** that has a page break and the visibility is set to true if it matches a condition based on a field in my dataset.

Trouble is whilst the majority of the report goes onto the second page based on the criteria given, there are a few exceptions. I have a similar requirement on the footer of the report, in that I don't want it to show on the first page of the report:

```
=IIF(isnothing(ReportItems!PupilName.Value),True,False)
```

This is working well and I'd like to use the same so show hide the visibility (and hence the page break) of the tablix but it's not working.

Any ideas or workarounds please.

Thanks,

Comment: What does it page break on? You may want to consider a list report as your "pages", with the appropriate boxes on that.

Comment: So the page break is set to break at the end of an empty tablix, and then the tablix visibility is currently set on the year of the pupils as some have less reports and others have more. I'd like to change it so that if all the reports complete on one the first page then there should be a break, otherwise no break. So I thought if I check for the contents of a textbox that should only be visible on the first page then that would work. Evidently not.

Comment: Have a look at using a list report, page breaking on Pupil. This will give you a page per pupil, and you can then add whatever tables, graphs, etc. into the list.

Comment: The report is already a list and it spans over multiple pages. It has many different tablix's but I'd like a page break after the first set of subject reports (tablix) only if they don't spill onto the second page (otherwise no page break). Hence my suggestion to look for a report item value as a check.

Comment: What does your list report page break on?

Comment: The list breaks on the unique id of the pupil.